# Python: change permissions (take ownership and full control) of registry keys to modify them

Tags: python, registry, uac, file-ownership

I would like to loop through all the registry keys and subkeys in a hive, find the value containing a specified string and replace it by a new one (I am adapting this [code](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2008-May/470898.html) using [winreg](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/winreg.html?highlight=winreg#module-winreg))

So far my code works on the keys whose `ownership` is `Administrator` and for which `Administrator` has `full control` but not on the other keys.

I could set the permissions of all my keys so that Administrator has full control but I would like to avoid that. Instead, I would like to only change the permissions of the keys that match the specified string. After the value is modified the permissions should be set back to what they were.

I have seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10617860/3154274) from 2012 but I would like to avoid installing a software for that.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody answered this question I thought I should share my solution for setting permissions on given keys using the [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) library:

```
import win32con as con
import win32api
import ntsecuritycon as ntc
import pywintypes
import win32security

key = win32api.RegOpenKey(con.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\\MyKey', 0, con.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
ksd = win32api.RegGetKeySecurity(key, con.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)

acl = pywintypes.ACL()
acl.AddAccessAllowedAce(ntc.GENERIC_ALL, win32security.ConvertStringSidToSid('S-1-5-18'))
acl.AddAccessAllowedAce(ntc.GENERIC_ALL, win32security.ConvertStringSidToSid('S-1-5-32-544'))

ksd.SetDacl(True, acl, False)

win32api.RegSetKeySecurity(key, con.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, ksd)
```

This will set the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\MyKey` key permission to `FULL CONTROL` for `SYSTEM` and `Administrators` but no other group will have read or write access. Note that the `ksd` variable has the original ACL in it until we run `.SetDacl()` on it, so if you want to write back the original permissions after the operation, just back that up to another variable like `ksd_bac` first, and then run `win32api.RegSetKeySecurity(key, con.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, ksd_bac)` after the operation.