# Appending an ACE to an existing ACL for registries

Tags: python, windows, permissions, registry, acl

I know how to add an ACL to a registry subkey thru AddAccessAllowedAce ([Python: change permissions (take ownership and full control) of registry keys to modify them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833089/python-change-permissions-take-ownership-and-full-control-of-registry-keys-to)) but this completely overwrites the ACL.

What if I only want to add an entry to the already existing ACL without touching all the other entries inside it?